# Jquery border plugin

Tags: jquery

I have this jquery code but i cant set the defaults behavior. Where (i mean the place in the code) can I write the default instruction? After return this.each or before or where? thank you for answer.

```
// corners v2
$.fn.corners2 = function (options) {
    // defaults settings for corners2
    var defaults = {
        // corners default style
        corners: 'default',

        // corners default radius 
        border_radius: '1',

        // borders default style
        border_style: 'solid',

        // borders default color without # symbol
        border_color: '#f7145a'
    };

    // options
    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        var element = $(this);

        // corners
        switch (options.corners) {
            // all
            case 'all':
                element.css({
                    '-webkit-border-radius': '' + options.radius + 'px',
                    '-moz-border-radius': '' + options.radius + 'px',
                    'border-radius': '' + options.radius + 'px'
                });
                break;

                // top left
            case 'top-left':
                element.css({
                    '-webkit-border-top-left-radius': '' + options.radius + 'px',
                    '-moz-border-radius-topleft': '' + options.radius + 'px',
                    'border-top-left-radius': '' + options.radius + 'px'
                });
                break;

                // top right
            case 'top-right':
                element.css({
                    '-webkit-border-top-right-radius': '' + options.radius + 'px',
                    '-moz-border-radius-topright': '' + options.radius + 'px',
                    'border-top-right-radius': '' + options.radius + 'px'
                });
                break;
        }
    });
};
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Also, can you fix the formatting of that code? It's way too spaced out.

Comment: You are calling the parameter 'border_radius' in the defaults, but then you reference it as radius in the code, you should use one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

```
// corners v2
$.fn.corners2 = function (opts) {
    // defaults settings for corners2
    var defaults = {
        // corners default style
        corners: 'default',

        // corners default radius 
        border_radius: '1',

        // borders default style
        border_style: 'solid',

        // borders default color
        border_color: '#f7145a'

        // border size
        border_width: 1
    };

    // options
    var options = $.extend({}, defaults, opts);

    return this.each(function () {
        var element = $(this);

        $(this).css({
            borderWidth:options.border_width,
            borderStyle:options.border_style,
            borderColor:options.border_color});

        // corners
        switch (options.corners) {
            // all
            case 'all':
                element.css({
                    '-webkit-border-radius': '' + options.border_radius + 'px',
                    '-moz-border-radius': '' + options.border_radius + 'px',
                    'border-radius': '' + options.border_radius + 'px'
                });
                break;

                // top left
            case 'top-left':
                element.css({
                    '-webkit-border-top-left-radius': '' + options.border_radius + 'px',
                    '-moz-border-radius-topleft': '' + options.border_radius + 'px',
                    'border-top-left-radius': '' + options.border_radius + 'px'
                });
                break;

                // top right
            case 'top-right':
                element.css({
                    '-webkit-border-top-right-radius': '' + options.border_radius + 'px',
                    '-moz-border-radius-topright': '' + options.border_radius + 'px',
                    'border-top-right-radius': '' + options.border_radius + 'px'
                });
                break;
            // Add cases for bottom-left, bottom-right, top, left, right, bottom, top-bottom, left-right, top-left-right, etc.
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Here I've made two changes, first I've changed the name of the default radius parameter from `border_radius` to `radius` because that is what your code is actually using, and second, I changed the name of the variable you pass in to `opt` from `options` to avoid conflicting with the name of the variable you use internally called `options`

Comment: And how can i set default property? I mean for example: $(this).css({'border':'5px solid black'}); Where Can I place this code for usage like a default. // When I use $('div').corners2(); so jquery  set $(this).css({'border':'5px solid black'});

Comment: Change `radius: '1'` to `radius: '5'`, change `border_color: '#f7145a'` to `border_color: 'black'`

Comment: I mean how to make program to set these values ​​if I do not enter anything into $ (this). corners2 (); When set something wrong, switch use the default: something but what when I set anything?

Comment: Updated answer to apply the border width, color, style for all cases of `corners`